# creating text file for each file in directory with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i created this with autohotkey but i couldn't organize them

```
^p::
Loop,  filename*.png
{
    SplitPath, A_LoopFileName,,,, name_no_ext
    FileAppend, %name_no_ext%`n, filename%name_no_ext%.txt
}
```

so i decided to write it with python but i can't make text file for each filename with os lib
and i can't remove dots or custom layout from filenames in text file

here my code :

```
import os 
import io 

dir_path = 'user/to/my/path'
#first add incremental number to the file name
i = 1
for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        os.rename(file,'#' +'{0:02d}'.format(i) + file)
        i+=1
#now add text file for each then write there names of the files
a = io.open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for filename in files:
        f = os.path.join(filename)
        f = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        f = f.replace('  ', '\n')
        a.write(str(f) + "\n")
```

file names are like this :

```
Angel    .Ghoul   .Angry    .black & waite     .Cannon Pink    ..png
```

and output of this script without renaming incremental number:

```
Angel

.Ghoul
 .Angry

.black & waite

 .Cannon Pink
```

i need to be like this
first text file:

```
#1
Angel
Ghoul
Angry
black & waite
Cannon Pink
```

second text file:

```
#2
Angel
Ghoul
Angry
black & waite
Chelsea Cucumber
```

n text file:

```
#n
based on file name
based on file name
based on file name
based on file name
based on file name
```

errors from incremental number for filenames:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Angel    .Ghoul   .Angry    .black & waite     .Cannon Pink    ..png' -> '#01Angel    .Ghoul   .Angry    .black & waite     .Cannon Pink    ..png'
```

Comment: I didn't review everything, but one issue is that you have to use the dirs and/or subdirs returned from `os.walk()` in order to get the appropriate full paths of the files. Look for examples of how to do that in other SO questions/answers.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly (in words, not code) what exactly you are trying to accomplish? After renaming all the .png files, what do you want to do in the text files?

Comment: I want to make a .txt file for each file with same name of filenames in text files in directory you can run autohotkey code to see what this script dose only problem is i can't organize them for example removing all dots from names in text files or blank spaces (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Do you want to rename the png files also? And rename to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
import os
import re

dir_path = "path/to/your/folder"
files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if f.endswith(".png")]

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    with open(f"#{i+1} {file.replace('.png', '.txt')}", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(f"#{i+1}\n")
        outfile.write("\n".join(re.split("\s\s+", file[:-4].replace(".","").strip())))
    os.rename(file, f"#{i+1} {file}")
```

Comment: thanks man"Do you want to rename the png files also? And rename to what?" yes and txt file also need to be like a png files names  like #1filename.png and #1filename.txt

Comment: @AliEbadi - Unclear. What exactly should your text file be named? And what exactly should your png file be named?

Comment: #1 filename .png and #1 pngfilename .txt and add numbers to txt too like #1 Angel
Ghoul
Angry
black & waite
Cannon Pink

Comment: i generate names with other script that's why names are so messy, so a normal generated png file are Angel    .Ghoul   .Angry    .black & waite     .Chelsea Cucumber    ..png and text file should be same like Angel    .Ghoul   .Angry    .black & waite     .Chelsea Cucumber    ..txt just adding number in first then name so like this: #1Angel    .Ghoul   .Angry    .black & waite     .Chelsea Cucumber    ..png and #1Angel    .Ghoul   .Angry    .black & waite     .Chelsea Cucumber    ..txt

Comment: works greats but how i can add numbers in text files ? just missing numbers in text files